# MySql add timestamp column with format

Tags: mysql, database

How could i insert into table a 'data' table a column(date) timestamp current_timestamp type with custom format like "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this seems the defaule forma so you could simply assign  this value  .. otherwise show  a proper data sample  and the column data type too.

Comment: So, could i write this sentence to do it?
`ALTER TABLE data ADD date TIMESTAMP('%Y/%m/%d %H:%m:%s' ) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: Date and time types have *no* format. They are binary values. How they appear depends on how the *client* formats the data when displaying it. The value is always the same. Your editor, application, IDE or workbench probably uses your locale's default format to display the data. When inserting data though, you should use parameterized queries to pass date-typed values, not strings.

Comment: And another alternative to timestamp to insert into a table a date column with a custom format?

Comment: Yes, i am using a virtual server on windows and phpmyadmin. so changing the windows configuration on it could run?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.I have followed the post 'Change the date format in phpmyadmin'.
Thanks.